# Cannot delete an sql object in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project and I have a problem with deleting an object. I have a model called Order and it looked like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    add = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="Undefined")
    guest = models.CharField(max_length=64, default="Anonymous")
```

I've already had an object and I decided to add another integer row. I forgot that integer rows must have integer default values and I just typed 'undefined'. When I made migrations, that was applied to my existing object but also gave me the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'undefined'
```

I've removed default value in the row but everytime I want to migrate (makemigrations works fine) I get the same error (this error above).

All I have to do is to delete this 'broken' object but I can't. I tried:

```
Orders.objects.all().delete()
```

it gave me the same error. And I also cannot access to this table via Django admin because of this error. What should I do?

Comment: the last migrations file that you had before removing the `IntegerField()` still has your default value `'undefined'` as default

Comment: Migrations are regular Python modules (i.e. `.py` files). Find the relevant migration and remove the offending code.

Comment: Thank you guys, I really didn't know that. It works great!